# Django access data from a variable in other method in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using method-based views, so my views.py file looks like this

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    **** DO SOMETHING HERE ****
    docs = someclass.somemethod(query)
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def analysis(request):
    x = query
    y = docs
    return render(request, 'analysis.html', {'query': x, 'docs': y})
```

Now I want to use the `query` variable in my other (analysis) method. One way is to make a class and then use `self.query` but I think I cannot do that like this in Django. I was looking for class based views but I don't know whether that will help. So please guide me how can I do that ?

Comment: Using class based views won't help - if you set `self.query` it will only be available for that request, not for future requests. If you want to access the result of `**** DO SOMETHING HERE ****`, then you need to store it somewhere, e.g. in the session.

Comment: What's stopping you from passing the `query` to analysis view in the url querystring, like you're doing in the index view?

Comment: It is not only about query. So lets say I used the query and process some data in that view. Now if I want to use that data in the other method. For example in ****DO SOMETHING**** I get a dictionary and I want to use that dictionary in the analysis view. Then it wouldn't work I guess

Comment: See my edits for explanation

Comment: View functions are pretty much stateless. You can rely on other things to keep state though. @Alasdair mentioned the session. There's also DB backed, and in this case it sounds like you want to use the front end to store some state. If `index` is sending back a piece of data to the front-end you want to use later, you can then send that piece of data to the `analysis` view next time you make a request to `analysis`.

Comment: @Alasdair I am doing `request.session['query'] = query` but then it throws error `no such table: django_session`. Can you guide how can I use sessions to store the data ?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't run `migrate` to create the table.

Comment: /yes exactly. I run migrate and now it is working. Thanks!